# Binding to multiple sources

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, collections

I'm plotting graphs with [D3](http://d3future.codeplex.com/). At this moment I'm doing it by binding this way:

```
<d3:ChartPlotter x:Name="plotter" ItemsSource="Charts" Margin="20">
```

And I Add/Remove items to Charts and the plotter updates automatically. Works very well.

The problem is that I need to bind from several collections, but obviously I can't set ItemsSource twice. I've read something about CompositeCollections, but almost every article is based on a StaticResource, that is not my case.

```
 <d3:ChartPlotter x:Name="plotter"Margin="20">
 <d3:ChartPlotter.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Charts}" />
      <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Charts2}" />
      </CompositeCollection>
  </d3:ChartPlotter.ItemsSource>
```

This code compiles but the binding doesn't work.

I've searched a lot but surprisingly I have not found the answer. I thought this hadto be a common task in WPF.

I'm open to other ways of binding multiple collections to a single ItemsSource, but adding manually each item from each sub collection to Charts I think it's too troublesome. Thank you.

EDIT:

I'm trying do it via MultiBinding and this is the scheme of the Converter

EDIT2:

Charts is an `ObservableCollection<LineGraph>`

```
public class ConcatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<LineGraph> enumerables = new ObservableCollection<LineGraph>();

        foreach (LineGraph line in values[0])
        {
            enumerables.Add(line);
        }

        foreach (LineGraph line in values[1])
        {
            enumerables.Add(line);
        }

        return enumerables;

    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can't compile because of this error: "foreach statement cannon operate in variables of type "object" because "object" does not contain public definition for "GetEnumerator".

Comment: Are Charts and Charts2 two separate collections? Also, is it fine if you just concat both collections?

Comment: Yes they are, didn't know about that concat operation, I will search about it immediately. Thanks

Comment: Don't search it, you won't find it! I was just asking if it was fine to just stick both collections together.

Comment: I think that concat method is not suitable for me because I'll need to concat my collections in everyplace that I add items. And probably I'll have several sources, not only 2. But thanks. Do you know if is possible to do something similar to concat but in XAML and compatible with binding?

Comment: Yep, MultiBinding + IMultiValueConverter. ;)

Comment: I'm trying to craft the converter but, could you guide me a bit with that? I don't know exactly how to make it to "sum" (add) each collection to previous one...

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I'm stucked with the converter, how would you implement that concat method given the situation?

Comment: Im just writing ththe answer down now, hang on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx). First, make a converter that will do what you want:

```
public class ConcatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<IEnumerable> enumerables = new List<IEnumerable>();
        foreach (object obj in values)
        {
            IEnumerable temp = obj as IEnumerable;
            if (temp == null) throw new ArgumentException();
            enumerables.Add(temp);
        }
        List<dynamic> enDynamic = new List<dynamic>();
        enDynamic.AddRange(enumerables);
        return Concat((dynamic)enDynamic);
    }
    private IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] toConcat)
    {
        return toConcat.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Concat(b));
    }
    private IEnumerable Concat(params IEnumerable[] toConcat)
    {
        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
        foreach (IEnumerable x in toConcat)
        {
            foreach (object n in x)
            {
                temp.Add(n);
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

(non-generic but I didn't want to use obtuse amounts of reflection)

Then add it to your window's resources:

```
<!--in your window declaration-->
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
<!--after that-->
<Window.Resources>
    <ttp:ConcatConverter x:Key="Concat"/>
</Window.Resources>
<!--finally:-->
<d3:ChartPlotter.ItemsSource>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Concat}">    
        <Binding Source="Charts"/>
        <Binding Source="Charts2"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</d3:ChartPlotter.ItemsSource>
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you very much. I've tried this but it doesn't work and I think the problem might be in the return type of temp. I don't know if my plotter can plot items from an ArrayList, I've tried to change it a List<IEnumerable> but the Add method fails (can't convert from object to IEnumerable).

Comment: It's probably because the return type isn't generic, I'll need to mess with some (a lot) of reflection.

Comment: @Sturm Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort but unfortunately still inoperative. The complexity has grown and I can't operate properly that expressions, isn't there a way just to merge Charts and Charts2 (only two)? Please see my edited question.

Comment: @Sturm Edited it again, if it doesn't work this time there must be something wrong with the DLR.

Comment: Well, I assume this is a lost battle but nota lost war. Sorry for bothering you so much, but if you could revise the snippet that I've pasted in EDIT2 would be awesome, I'll be happy if I just could do that (for now). Thanks again