# How to bind 2 CollectionViewSource to a GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

We have two CollectionViewSource

```
<CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding CategoryData}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="TopItemsQuestionData"            
        d:Source="{Binding AllCategory, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:DataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>

    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSourcePOI"
        Source="{Binding CategoryData}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="TopItemsQuestionDataPOI"
        d:Source="{Binding AllCategory, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:DataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

and we would like to Bind those two CollectionViewSource to this Data GridView

```
 <GridView
       ...
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSourcePOI}}"
```

The Binding, of course, has to be made on this ItemSource. 
The problem is that the ItemSource accepts only one "Binding Source" at time and we'd like to link this to both of our CollectionViewSource. Are there any chance to link them together ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050501/binding-to-multiple-sources/17051277#17051277

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a general Type (maybe an abstract class that generalize your collections) and bind it to GridView

Answer (score 1):

I think that in GridView you can't use MultiBinding class

Comment: Try to use CollectionContainer class [Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.data.collectioncontainer.aspx)